# What does "I like the direction of this" mean?

Tags: proverbs

**Context:** After I suggested something, someone replied with: "I actually like the direction of this.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means he/she doesn't actually like the suggestion directly, rather the idea behind the suggestion. 
Your suggestion may not be the perfect fit, but it is pointing to some valid solution. Or your suggestion is useful with some modification.

Answer (score 1):

**go in the right direction** an idiom  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/direction)

> 1. Lit. to head or travel in the right direction.
> 2. Fig. [for plans or intentions] to be progressing sensibly.

As in:

> "I actually like the direction/plan/intention of this."

Answer (score 0):

'I like the direction of this.'

Simply means that he/she likes the concept behind your idea, but maybe not the idea as a whole.